# Adodb recordset count in excel

Tags: excel, vba

With the help of below coding any I am able to copy the required data from one sheet to another sheet but it is showing incorrect records count as "-1". 
I am not sure as to what went wrong.

This coding is showing "-1" 
`mrs.RecordCount`

Full coding

```
Dim sSQLQry As String
Dim ReturnArray
Dim Conn As New adodb.Connection
Dim mrs As New adodb.Recordset
Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"
Conn.Open sconnect

sSQLSting = "SELECT * From [DataSheet$A1:F4247]" 
mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn
MsgBox mrs.RecordCount

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset mrs
Close Recordset
mrs.Close
Conn.Close
```

Comment: `Recordcount` only works with cursors that are Clientside, Serverside -
 Static, or Serverside - Keyset. You have a forward-only cursor.

Comment: Agree with @Rory. Try `mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn, 3, 1`. This is server-side static and read-only.